# Navigation Controller shows black screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I was learning iOS dev and met some problems with Navigation Controller.

I created a SingleView application then use "Embed In Navigation Controller" to get a navigation control.

The problem I met is, after the app successfully build up, only the navigation bar is visible, other UI components are nothing but pure black. I've tried on real device, clean/rebuild, delete the app & re-build, all got the same result.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot of storyboard:

[image]

When Navigation Controller is clicked:

[image]

I have tried update the constraints and frames, so there's no amber triangle warnings.

"Is Initial View Controller" is already ticked.

Code:

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

=== UPDATE ====

It's my mistake to use a `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewController`

Please see the accepted answer for details.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your xib/storyboard, whatever you are using.

Comment: Any chance that you overwrote `viewDidLoad` method and forgot to call super?

Comment: @AyanSengupta thx, I've updated with screenshots of storyboard.

Comment: @dariaa thx, I just confirmed that `[super viewDidLoad]` is the only line inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Have you tried removing the root segue from nav controller to root view controller and then reassigning? Please also make sure that you are doing something tricky in your code. Do you have any view with black background by any chance?

Comment: @AyanSengupta I'm not quite understand this? I think the navigation controller is already the root view controller? I see this inside the "Triggered Segues" when I clicking the Navigation Controller: root view controller ----x View Controller(The one showing 99:99). And I don't have any black background...

Comment: "Triggered Segues" means the segues that are invoked from a particular VC. In your example, the root segue invoked by navigationController is x view controller and that means when the navigation controller loads, it invokes it root segue and that in turn should load the x view controller VC as the root view controller of the navigation controller. I have asked you just removing and reassigning the segue from the nav controller to your x view controller. Please also make sure that the `view` outlet of your x view controller is set properly.

Comment: @AyanSengupta I deleted the Navigation controller, and it still gives me a blackscreen

Comment: I have not asked you to delete the nav controller but the root segue from it. Can you please post your project somewhere so that we can check if anything unusual is happening underneath.

Comment: @AyanSengupta thank you although P.Sami solved this for me, can I still ask how to "removing & re-assigning the segue from the nav controller" like you said?

Comment: Just click on the segue (the arrow between VCs) and press "delete" from the keyboard. And you would get it removed. To reassign, select the source VC in your storyboard>>hold "control">>drag to another VC on the storyboard and release>>select the type of segue from the list that appears and the segue is set. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @AyanSengupta cheers mate, good to know that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at your code. In ViewController.h you have:

```
@interface ViewController : UINavigationController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Just change that to

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

And it will show up!

The navigation controller is trying to show another empty navigation controller! :)

Comment: thx. I just tried delete the navigation controller, so that it will got directly to the view controller, but it didn't work. In my storyboard it doesn't have "File Owner". It seems only exist in an older version?

Comment: @ss1271 File Owner is not an older concept but that is unavailable if you use storyboard. Its still available through xib.

Comment: @P.Sami thx, I just tried but still not work. I have updated my question with the link to my project (.zip file), could you have time to check that?

Comment: @ss1271 I think you already know by now what you were missing! So I didn't post something extra. Glad that it helped :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks! You saved my time! It happens (inheriting from the UINavigationViewController) because of saving the past inherited superclass in class creation wizard. The Xcode just saves your last input and it leads these errors.