# Segue lead to black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I created the simple table view that displays the list of cities .Then i created simple city class that initialises city object.Then in viewcontroller i retrieve Data from url in cityArray.Then displayed that array into tableview. Then i sent the selected row data in to detail ViewController using this function

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *dvc=[[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    //retrive the current selected city
    City *currentCity=[cityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dvc.name=currentCity.cityName;
    dvc.population=currentCity.cityPopulation;
    dvc.country=currentCity.cityCounrty;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

1- I want the list of cities should display list of corresponding countries  in subtitle for this i following changes in this function but it is not working

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
   // cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];
    // retrieve the current city object for use with this indexpath.row
    City *currentCity=[cityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=currentCity.cityName;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=currentCity.cityCounrty;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}
```

2- I want when the user taps tableview cell in list of cities. The table view should display the corresponding detail of city in DetailViewController.But DetailViewController is displaying black screen.How i can remove this back screen and get the actual record ?
You can download the sample project from this link for correction .https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8Snd3lhVFpZTWJveVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to instantiate your DetailViewController using [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"]

Comment: i have tried answer given on these links .but non of them working .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929039/pushviewcontroller-leads-to-black-screen... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259246/navigation-controller-shows-black-screen.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407841/navigation-controller-showing-black-screen

Comment: Have you given an identifier for DetailViewController in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in this line

```
 DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
```

Whenever you use storyboard and trying to push a Viewcontroller, you need to give the controller an identifier in your storyBoard, instead of doing alloc init.

Just replace your alloc init with this line and it will work for you.

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

And yes, make sure you give identifier in your StoryBoard.

Comment: @Wwwwwwwwwwwww did my solution solved your problem?  If yes you can upvote and mark it as answer. It may help others.